# How to read from a url directly as a list verbatim?

Tags: python, json, urllib

I have a url that contains just a list. For example, the path
https://somepath.com/dev/doc/72
returns simply (no html code):

```
[
  "A/RES/72/1", 
  "A/RES/72/2", 
  "A/RES/72/3", 
  "A/RES/72/4"
]
```

I want to take the entire contents (including the square brackets) and make this into a list. Doing it by hand, I can copy/paste as a list like this:

```
docs = [
  "A/RES/72/1", 
  "A/RES/72/2", 
  "A/RES/72/3", 
  "A/RES/72/4"
]
print(docs)
['A/RES/72/1', 'A/RES/72/2', 'A/RES/72/3', 'A/RES/72/4']
```

I would like to pass the content of the url to the list.

I tried the following

```
link = "https://somepath.com/dev/doc/72"
f = urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print(myfile)
b'[\n  "A/RES/72/1", \n  "A/RES/72/2", \n  "A/RES/72/3", \n  "A/RES/72/4"\n]\n
```

It's a mess with new lines and not a list.

I'm guessing I would have to parse each line, removing the \n character, or something like this:
`file.read().splitlines()`
, but that seems overly complicated for such a simple input.

I've seen many solutions that parse .csv files, read inputs from each line, etc. But nothing to deal with a list that is already made and just needs to be called. Thanks for any help and pointers.

edit: 
I tried this:

```
import urllib.request  # the lib that handles the url stuff
link = "https://somepath.com/dev/doc/72"
a=[]
for line in urllib.request.urlopen(link):
    print(line.decode('utf-8'))
    a.append(line)

a
```

The `print` command gives me something close to what I want. But the `append` command gives me a mess again:

```
[b'[\n',
 b'  "A/RES/72/1", \n',
 b'  "A/RES/72/2", \n',
 b'  "A/RES/72/3", \n',
 b'  "A/RES/72/4"\n',
 b']\n']
```

Edit: Turns out the url is serving a JSON. The solution by fuglede below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60119016/10764078):

```
import requests
docs = requests.get('https://somepath.com/dev/doc/72').json()
```

I'm going to do some reading on JSON.

Comment: Would `ast.literal_eval()` do the trick?

Comment: @AMC: It fails on the example given.

Comment: What is the `Content-Type:` on the returned value? It looks like it could be JSON, and [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) has support for parsing JSON replies for you, or you could use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse it yourself.

Comment: Have you tried to `a.append(line.decode('utf-8'))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming what the site is sending you is JSON, with `requests`, this would be obtainable through

```
import requests
docs = requests.get('https://somepath.com/dev/doc/72').json()
```

Comment: That work perfectly. I didn't realize it was JSON (no documentation...). Not it is all so clear. A million thanks.

Comment: These days JSON is rather ubiquitous as a data format for HTTP based APIs, so it's quite normal to see it used without mention.

Answer (score 0):

This works w/ the example you provided:

```
ast.literal_eval(str(myfile)[2:-1].replace("\\n",""))
```

Comment: I would have to look at ask.literal_eval(). Fuglede's answers works well, so I accepted that one. I'll try yours in the future. Thanks!